# Is there a online FTP i can put on my website?

Tags: ftp

Im trying to find something so that i can modify, delete etc my code on the web. Do y'all have any good ones you recommend? Im trying to find it because i have a co-dev that cant access my server for some reason.

I tried googel/youtube searching it but found nothing

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you have some kind of static website in production with html files you need to update for example? If you just need a collaboration tool for development for managing a codebase together with a coworker you might need a code repository like GitHub.com